# Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

When I try to run my flutter code in Android Studio, I get this error:

```bash
Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:5:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
import 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:7:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
import 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/cubits/signInCubit.dart:6:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
import 'authCubit.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:62:27: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      if (authProvider == AuthProvider.email) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:136:15: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      signOut(AuthProvider.email);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:159:21: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
    if (provider == AuthProvider.fb) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:161:28: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
    } else if (provider == AuthProvider.gmail) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:163:28: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
    } else if (provider == AuthProvider.mobile) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:165:28: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
    } else if (provider == AuthProvider.apple) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:199:15: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      signOut(AuthProvider.mobile);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:207:22: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      authProvider = AuthProvider.fb;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:209:22: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      authProvider = AuthProvider.gmail;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:211:22: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      authProvider = AuthProvider.mobile;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:213:22: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      authProvider = AuthProvider.apple;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRepository.dart:215:22: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      authProvider = AuthProvider.email;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/otp_screen.dart:385:23: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
                      AuthProvider.mobile,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/otp_screen.dart:398:31: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
                authProvider: AuthProvider.mobile,
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:167:27: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      if (authProvider == AuthProvider.gmail) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:172:34: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      } else if (authProvider == AuthProvider.mobile) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:178:34: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      } else if (authProvider == AuthProvider.email) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:184:34: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
      } else if (authProvider == AuthProvider.apple) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/features/auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:294:25: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'.
    if (authProvider == AuthProvider.gmail) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/macbook/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: **AuthProvider** this class exist in multiple files you imported in one file. 
As for example one of your file imported: 

   

     `import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart'`

 and,

     `import 'package:flutterquiz/features/auth/cubits/authCubit.dart'`

Both of these files have AuthProvider class which causing the error. 

Change your **AuthProvider** class name to something else is the solution here. So it won't conflict with `firebase_auth` package's AuthProvider class.

Comment: or, `import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' as firebase` then use `firebase.AuthProvider` where you need it.

Comment: I solve it by : I update the sdk in android studio, I run flutter pub get in terminal I open the folder of code source in android studio I run it and it work it good

Comment: @Azgaou It's possible that your `flutter pub get` command simply fetched an older version of the firebase_auth package without the conflicting export. The underlying issue is likely still there, waiting for your next `flutter pub upgrade`—see my answer for details.

Comment: yes your information is absolutely correct flutter pub get command simply fetched an older version of the firebase_auth package without the conflicting export. when I try to update the app I got the error and I solve it by Rename my own AuthProvider class to avoid the collision. thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Forcing usage of version `4.12.0` worked for me:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_auth: "4.12.0"
```

As [@lukenntt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297460/lukemmtt) mentioned it appears that `firebase_auth` version `4.13.0` introduces a conflict. Using `hide` or aliases does not seem to be enough in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is the result of a naming collision caused by the recent update to the `firebase_auth` package, specifically version 4.13.0, which now exports an `AuthProvider` class. This change was introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/11470) and is mentioned in the [release notes](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog) dated November 9, 2023.

Shahed Emon pointed out the possible fixes in his comment above:

- Rename your own `AuthProvider` class to avoid the collision, or...
- Use an alias when importing the conflicting class from the `firebase_auth` package, like this:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' as firebase;
```

By using aliasing when importing the `firebase_auth` package, you can prevent the `AuthProvider` from that package from being unintentionally merged into your existing code, which does not reference `firebase_auth`'s `AuthProvider`.

For reference, this is was the error I was getting:

> Failed to build iOS app
>
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
>
> Error (Xcode):
> lib/feature/auth/provider/firebase_auth_provider.dart:3:1: Error:
> 'AuthProvider' is imported from both
> 'package:app/feature/auth/provider/auth_provider.dart' and
> 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart'.